# Difference between windows update and office update

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, updates

Is there any difference in update protocol ? I got this problem on of my virtual machines. System is constantly complaining about connection (I think it's due to chunk size on proxy) but office is updating normally without any problems. Therefore question - couldn't find related problem on forum. Someone can explain and maybe help to redirect system updates - to the very same settings which office uses ?

Comment: Windows Updates will only update Windows components. Microsoft Updates will do Windows, Office and any other MS software such as Visual C++ runtimes. The procedure to enable MS updates is a little different depending on the version of OS. Same update mechanism for both.

Comment: okay fully understand, but why then office is updating and system cannot...... do you think it is possible that chunk sizes of files are smaller for office rather than for system itself?

Comment: Other than Office service packs, yes they are usually smaller.